# Detect type/enum for purposes of collision between different game objects/classes

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to make a collision detection system where each game object reacts differently to other game objects by checking what type the game object it collides with is.

I keep getting:

> 'Rat' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'.

This the code I use to detect what kind of objects collide and decide what to do when an object collides with another of a certain type:

```
switch (other.Type) {
    case Rat:
        float tooClose = (Radius * 2) - distance.Length();
        distance.Normalize();

        PositionAfterCollisions += distance * tooClose * 0.5f;
        VelocityAfterCollisions = -Velocity;
}
```

`'other'` is here a reference to a game object in the collision list.

And this is from the top of the class/GameObjectI'm trying to identify + the class it inherits from:

```
public enum ObjectType
{
    Default,
    Player,
    Rat,
    Cheese,
    Trap,
    Home
}
public ObjectType Type = ObjectType.Rat;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C#, enums are always qualified by name.

You'd need

```
case ObjectType.Rat:
```

Comment: Now I get this error instead: Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case 2:') to another